# Creating the larger replica of box with

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created box with image, title, link and few data which is here:

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/s5q9w/5/)

I want to create the replica of div box which should be little larger then actually. Actually I want to show it highlighted with little larger size on hover.

I create second copy in fiddle with `item2` class by increased height but no effect.

can some one tell me how to do this?

I found this while googling

```
$('#theDiv').clone().css('-webkit-transform', 'scale(.125, .125)');
```

and

```
var w = $("#thediv").width();
  var clone = $('#thediv').clone().css("width", w/8);
```

But I could not figure out with it.

Comment: There is no element with an ID of `theDiv` in your JSFiddle; nor is there any JavaScript.

Comment: After looking into your fiddle I noticed that you are applying the height 60px for item2, but not for the description, title and the image and hence the item2 box is 60px in height but not its children

You need to adjust the height for the image,description,title elements also

Comment: @Ashish: is there any other way so that all other element's size also changes relatively by changing parent div's size

Answer (score 0):

You're duplicating IDs. IDs must be unique in HTML, and JavaScript will only search for the first ID it finds and no more:

```
var w = $("#thediv").width();
var clone = $('#thediv').clone().attr('id', 'newId').css("width", w/8);
```

Comment: Thanks, can you please give fiddle

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS hover to d this

Fiddle: [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/karimkhan/s5q9w/21/)

```
.item:hover h6 {
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.item:hover .moreBtn img {
    margin-top: 4px;
}

.item:hover .moreBtn {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    color: red;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-style:italic;
    }
.item:hover .pillBtn {
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    background:#7CDD97;
    padding: 21px 70px 21.0px 70px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.item:hover {
    background:#F3F3F3;
    height: 70px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
.item:hover .media-object {
    height: 70px;
    width: 140px;
}
```